# Circuit seems to lack something

Tags: relay

http://www.electronicecircuits.com/electronic-circuits/cd4060-timer-circuit-1-minute-to-2-hours
I've replicated the circuit in the given link but \$D_2\$ in my circuit doesn't work at all. Also, the relay doesn't operate. I tried unplugging the relay.
LED \$D_1\$ is normally working and blinks with a time interval which I can change using \$VR_1\$.

Comment: Are you sure you have Q1 the right way around?

Comment: Yes, i checked it again, it's right.

Comment: Is there a voltage across R3 when it should be on? From pin 3 to ground?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: Put on your properly-grounded antistatic wrist strap and replace the IC.

Comment: Temporarily disconnect D3 and the relay, and move R3 from pin 3 to pin 7. Does D2 now blink? Does D1 still blink?

Comment: I've changed the IC, disconnected D3 and the relay. D2 is now working along with D1 and they both don't blink.

Comment: Also, there is 11 mohm voltage between pin3 and ground.

Comment: If both LEDs are now permanently lit then the CD4060 is either open circuit or cannot supply enough output current to drive the two loads. Do the LEDs change brightness at all (in time with the blinking)? What is the voltage on pin7? What happens if you disconnect R3? Measure the resistance of R3, what is it?

Comment: Move R3 to pin 6, 5, 3 etc. Does LED2 blink slower as you move down the chain? Also, measure the power supply voltage while the LEDs are blinking. Is it stable?

Comment: I rebuilt the circuit completely. Relay is disconnected and R3 is connected to pin7. This time, Led1 blinks and Led2 begins closed. After four cycles, Led2 lights up and Led1 keeps open, after four cycles, Led2 closes and returns to beginning. Led1 keeps changing intensity periodically while Led2 is open. Now i'm confused

Comment: Sorry, looks like i made a silly mistake, the R3 was at Pin6 instead of 7. At Pin7, They are both open, led1 changes intensity. When i change pins, number of cycles change. Battery voltage changes about 0.30 Volts according to Led1's brightness and whether Led2 is open.

Comment: If you solved the problem and you think the solution is worth mentioning, you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, dear people of stackexchange, I want to thank you all for your time and effort, you helped me to a great extent to understand this circuit, and general electronics. And I want to apologise for my unmutable idiocity. Bruce was right, my chip couldn't supply enough current. Because i didn't supply it any current at all. After trying many different circuits and having a night's sleep, i managed to connect Pin 16 to 9V input.

Answer (score 0):

Are you waiting long enough for the output at Pin 3 to turn on?  It would be 1/1024 the rate of the D1 signal, or 1024 x the duration.